# null data from server ,which under a non null condition?

Tags: objective-c

I got from server a response :

```
 [NSURLConnection
     sendAsynchronousRequest:request
     queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                         NSData *data,
                         NSError *error)
     {

         if ([data length] >0 && error == nil)
         {
             NSLog(@"DATA1: %@",data);
             NSString *content;
             content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
             NSLog(@"DATA2: %@",content);
```

something is strange here. the second `NSLOG` shows me a `null` data- but if the data is null how could he pass the `if statement` ?
the first log show me: `<636f6e66 69726d65 64>` .

I have to say that sometimes it do work ! it depend on the values somehow ...

Comment: You should consider reading the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the with first log, you're printing the `NSData` instance, and with the second, the `NSString` you want to generate from the data. But if the data is not valid UTF-8 (which may be the case, since it's not NUL-terminated, and `stringWithUTF8String:` requires a NUL-terminated string, so it doesn't stop at the end and it might read garbage), then it returns `nil`.

What you want is:

```
content = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:data.bytes length:data.length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```